# When adding a Volume to a deployment of 3 pods, why the service needs to be restarted so the changes take place?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, minikube

I installed minikube and created a simple application with a deployment of 3 pods and a service that points to this deployment.

This is a very simple nginx image, I am using it just to learn the tooling.

At some point, I changed my pods inside the deployment to have a volume, so I deleted the deployment and recreated (this is defined by deployment.yaml).

However, the mounting point only worked after I deleted the service and re-created it again (defined by service.yaml).

Why the service needed to be recreated so the mounting point worked inside the pod?

This service file had no changes whatsoever, and my understanding was that services reached the pods based on selector rules and that these (deployments and services) could be created and modified independently without any specific tie.

Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to see the issue without the manifests of service and deployment and how it is identified "mounting point only worked after I deleted the service". Have you checked the kubelet log telling trying to mount? What are the output of kubectl describe svc/pod/deployment?

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed some other change as Service object has no effect on Pods of the Deployment that it is pointing to